# How to check jq result is null or not?

Tags: json, bash, shell, null, jq

I'm using jq to parse some JSON. I want to check whether a property exists or not. If it exists I always want to get the first element in the array. Based on this I want to use `if then ... else`.

My code looks like this:

```
JSON_INPUT='{"var1":[{"foo":"bar"}],"var2":[{"fooooo":"baaaaar"}]}'
VAR2=$(echo $JSON_INPUT | jq  '.["var2"] | .[0]')
if [ -z "${VAR2}" ]
then
    echo "does not exist"
    # do some stuff...
else
    echo "exist"
    # do some stuff...
fi
```

The JSON_INPUT may contain `var2` but must not. If it does not exist `VAR2` will be null. But I'm not able to check for this null value. Where is the error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Where is the error?

Replace

```
[ -z "${VAR2}" ]
```

with

```
[ "${VAR2}" = "null" ]
```

because `jq` returns string `null` if `var2` is not found in JSON file.

---

Or use `--exit-status`:

```
if echo "$JSON_INPUT" | jq --exit-status '.var2' >/dev/null; then 
  echo "exists"
else
  echo "does not exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

> I want to check whether a property exists or not. If it exists I always want to get the first element in the array ...

The condition can best be expressed as:

```
if has("var2")
```

so since you seem to want VAR2 to be null if the condition is not met, you could write:

```
VAR2=$(jq 'if has("var2") then .["var2"][0] else null end')
```

If the condition is not met, then we would find:

```
echo "$VAR2"
null
```

There is a small problem, here, though: for example, what if the array's first value is `null`?

So a more discriminating approach would be to write:

```
 VAR2=$(jq 'if has("var2") then .["var2"][0] else empty end')
```

Even if neither of these approaches is exactly what you want, they illustrate that putting as much of the logic inside the jq program as possible yields a tidy, easy-to-understand, and efficient solution.